# How to refactor Ruby's #{} method in JavaScript which I write

Tags: javascript

When I'm writing Javascript code, I feel miss Ruby's #{} method.So I implement it in JS. 
But this code is not clean and beautiful. I want to make this method safe, But I can't do it.
Do you have any idea that this code makes safe or beautiful? Thanks in advance.

```
String.prototype.to_s = function(){
    var str = this.toString();


    // convert function is bad  because it use eval...
    var convert = function(s){
        return eval(s);
    };

    // It's slower because call ReGexp method too many times.
    while(/#{(\w+)}/.test(str)){


        var matchStr =RegExp.$1;

        var str = str.replace(/#{(\w+)}/,convert(matchStr));

    }
    return str;
};



var name = "nobi";

var age = 23;

var body = "I'm #{name} and I am #{age} years old".to_s();
// I'm nobi and I am 23 years old.


console.log(body);
```

Comment: When it boils down to it this is basically a template, much like mustache, handlebars and ExtJS templates. Maybe look at how they are implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sort of hack can’t be made “beautiful” – it doesn’t even work for non-globals. Given ES6 support, though, you don’t need the hack; string interpolation is now a part of the language.

```
var body = `I'm ${name} and I am ${age} years old`;
```

Failing that, string concatenation is often readable enough with ES5 and earlier:

```
var body = "I'm " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old";
```

[CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), a language that compiles to JavaScript, also supports this feature.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to what you want would be a templating system, such as [**mustache**](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js). It lets you do things like:

```
var person = {
  name: "nobi",
  age: 23
};

var output = Mustache.render("I'm {{name}} and I am {{age}} years old.", person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use coffeescript.

http://coffeescript.org/#strings

Also `#{}` isn't a method in Ruby, it's called "string interpolation".

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation